# Searching for buttons using the button's text attribute

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to search for a button's text and return any buttons which match that search.

E.g. I have three buttons, each with the button text: One, Two & Three.
When I search for "Two", I want the button which has the button test "Two" to display.

I've seen how this is done with SearchView but that is only for a string and I'm unsure of how to approach for button text

This is my `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static  ListView lv;
private static Button bt, bt2, bt3;

ArrayList<Button> items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(0, bt);
    items.add(1, bt2);
    items.add(2, bt3);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.item, items));
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Button> {
    private int layout;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Button> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layout = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mainViewholder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.bt = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            viewHolder.bt2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonn);
            viewHolder.bt3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonnn);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            mainViewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {
    Button bt;
    Button bt2;
    Button bt3;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do. But, there are a few things in the code we don't normally do with ListView.

1. You should pass a collection of data models to the ArrayAdatper, not UI controls.
2. Your MyListAdapter doesn't use the given items.
3. You don't need to specify the position when adding data to ArrayList.

It seems, in your code, you have 3 buttons on each row. So, your data model should contain the text to be displayed on 3 buttons and 3 booleans to control their visibility. you search the button text in the models and change the boolean value, then call notifyDataSetChanged. GetView will be called for each row for you to update the UI.

Comment: I have made my question very clear.Thnks for the info on ListView,but that does not answer my question.